# Docker-compose volume resetting when upgrading image

Tags: docker, docker-compose, grafana, docker-volume

I have a docker image of Grafana 8.0.5. I created a volume using `docker volume create grafana-storage`

I can stop the volume, and bring it back up with no data loss.

However, if I update my docker-compose.yml to point to the latest version, 8.0.6, and re-run `docker-compose up -d` the volume goes back to a default install, losing any of my previously created dashboards, accounts, data sources, etc.

As far as I understand, I shouldn't lose any data, since it should all be in the volume. How do you update images without resetting the volume

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.3"

volumes:
  grafana-storage:
    external: true

services:

  grafana:
    image: "grafana/grafana:8.0.6"
    container_name: "grafana"
    volumes:
      - "grafana-storage:/usr/src/grafana"
```

Docker Version:

```
Docker version 20.10.7, build f0df350
```

Docker-Compose Version:

```
docker-compose version 1.29.2, build 5becea4c
```

docker ps:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                   COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                                           NAMES
3fb6da4a8de9   grafana/grafana:8.0.6   "/run.sh"                17 minutes ago   Up 17 minutes   3000/tcp                                        grafana
046892ab0a7b   traefik:v2.0            "/entrypoint.sh --pr…"   46 minutes ago   Up 23 minutes   80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp, :::443->443/tcp   traefik
```

docker volume ls:

```
DRIVER    VOLUME NAME
local     grafana-storage
```

Comment: Don't know the solution, but 2 things to try: 1) How does a 'docker volumer inspect' look like? 2) Instead of 'grafana-storage' try something like './grafanastorage' (No dash and put the volume in your own folders instead of in Docker folders).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is not stored in `/usr/src/grafana` but in `/var/lib/grafana`. In consequence, your volume-definition in `docker-compose.yml` is wrong and everytime the container is recreated, the data is lost.

Change the path to `/var/lib/grafana` and it should work:

```
services:
  grafana:
    [...]
    volumes:
      - "grafana-storage:/var/lib/grafana"
```

Comment: Changing the path was correct. Are volume paths image depependent, then? I assumed it was similar to if I had downloaded/unzipped grafana, or any other image, into a directory of my choosing

Comment: Yes, every image defines its own paths which are mostly documented somewhere. For example, Grafana has the documentation [here](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/administration/configure-docker/#default-paths).